# Flex SDK installer fails to download https://github.com/swfobject/swfobject/archive/2.2.zip

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder

I am trying to install Apache Flex SDK 4.16.1 + AIR 31.0 or AIR 32.0 with the latest Apache Flex installer - tried it on both Win 7 and Win 10. Starting it with administrator rights.

At some point the installer just stops with this message, nothing happens after that.

Downloading 2.2.zip from: https://github.com/swfobject/swfobject/archive

I can open https://github.com/swfobject/swfobject/archive/2.2.zip  in the browser just fine, it downloads the file.

Full install log contents:

```
Installer path: C:\Users\Myuser\AppData\Roaming\org.apache.flex.installapacheflex\Local Store\Win64
Installer version 3.3.2 (windows)
Available Memory: 49291264 (64-bit)
Using Locale: de_AT
Fetched the SDK download mirror URL from the CGI.
SDK version Apache Flex SDK 4.16.1
AIR version 32.0
Flash Player version 32.0
Creating Apache Flex home
Creating temporary directory
Downloading Apache Flex SDK from: https://mirror.klaus-uwe.me/apache/flex/4.16.1/binaries/apache-flex-sdk-4.16.1-bin.zip
Verifying Apache Flex SDK MD5 Signature
The Apache Flex SDK MD5 Signature of the downloaded files matches the reference. The file is valid.
Uncompressing: C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\sdks\4.16.1 AIR 32\temp\apache-flex-sdk-4.16.1-bin.zip
Finished uncompressing: C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\sdks\4.16.1 AIR 32\temp\apache-flex-sdk-4.16.1-bin.zip
Downloading 2.2.zip from: https://github.com/swfobject/swfobject/archive
```

Besides of that every second time it aborts with the following message, but that's another story

Installation aborted: http://flex.apache.org/track-installer.html?failure=true&label=Apache Flex SDK 4.16.1&version=4.16.1&os=windows&installerversion=3.3.2&info=Error #2031

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is an issue with the installer, after some links where changed/expired. Try downloading with AIR 31 or 30 then update air by replacing files from either AIR32 from adobe (doesnt work for mobile any more) or AIR33 from Harman.